# Linq outer join and specify DefaultIfEmpty values - anonymous type does not contain a definition for defaultifempty .. requires a receiver of type

Tags: c#, linq, outer-join

I have a linq query that performs 2 outer joins like this:

```
            var finalDataSet = from a in alpha
                                join b in beta on a.field1 equals b.field1
                                // *outer join*
                                join c in charlie on a.field2 equals c.field2 into c_2
                                from c2 in c_2.DefaultIfEmpty(new MyObject1 { MyProperty1 = (string) String.Empty, MyProperty2 = (DateTime?) null })
                                join d in delta on a.field3 equals d.field3
                                // *outer join*
                                join e in echo on a.field4 equals e.field4 into e_2
                                from e2 in e_2.DefaultIfEmpty(new MyObject2 { MyProperty3 = String.Empty, MyProperty4 = String.Empty })
                                orderby a.field1
                                select new
                                {
                                    FinalProperty1 = a.field1,
                                    FinalProperty2 = a.field2,
                                    etc ...
```

.. and my type definitions for the types I'm newing up for the 'DefaultIfEmpty'  values:

MyObject1:

```
public class MyObject1
{
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    public DateTime? MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

MyObject2:

```
public class MyObject2
{
    public string MyProperty3 { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty4 { get; set; }
}
```

The 2nd outer join (to 'echo') is fine, but for the 1st, I get the compiler error when I reference c_2 on this line:

```
from c2 in **c_2**  --> compiler doesn't like the reference to c_2
```

I get this error:

```
IEnumerable <<anonymous type: string Property1, DateTime? Property2 >> does not contain a definition for 'DefaultIfEmpty' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.DefaultIfEmpty' <MyObject1>(IQueryable<MyObject1>, MyObject1)' requires a receive of type 'IQueryable<LatestExpiredSchedule>'
```

Why am I getting this error for my 1st join and not the 2nd? If I change my 1st join to:

```
from e2 in e_2.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

I don't get an error, but I need to explicitly specify defaults. What does the error message really mean, and how do I need to specify the defaults for my 1st left outer join?

Comment: See msdn left outer join : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer - my 'charlie' in the above query was the result of a linq query and so return anonymous types. I needed to construct an object of MyObject1 for each of the results returned by that query.